# What is the better way to add commas to multiple elements string output?

Tags: java, string, groovy

I need to put comma separated values into `ourOutput` (for future output). So, what I need is to add commas and remove last unnecessary comma or check if comma should be placed.

I came to two following solutions:

1st approach:

```
ourOutput  = ''<<'';
for (int i = 0; i< 10, i++) {
  if (/*some condition goes here*/) {
    if (ourOutput.size() == 0) {
      ourOutput << ', '
    } 
    ourOutput << i;
  }
}
```

pros: don't change resulting string
cons: check on each iteration;

2nd approach:

```
ourOutput  = ''<<'';
for (int i = 0; i< 10, i++) {
  if (/*some condition goes here*/) {
    ourOutput << i << ', ';
  }
}
if (ourOutput.size() != 0) {
  ourOutput.setLength(ourOutput.length() - 2);
}
```

pros: don't check each time
cons: modifying resulting string.

Please advise, which one to use or maybe there is some better way to do that?

p.s. code written in groovy, feel free to replace ''<<'' with `new StringBuilder()` and `<<` with `.append()` so it became java-compilable.

Comment: In your first approach, you could use a boolean instead of checking the size. That's the approach I would use.

Comment: Is this Java or C++? I am not sure what `ourOutput << i << ', '` is.

Comment: You want the answer in Groovy?  Or are you looking for a pure Java answer?  If Groovy...just use [`join(',')`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9699780/6509) rather than trying to re-invent the wheel

Comment: @tim, sory can't mark 2 answers as correct, so choose that one that took more votes. Anyway many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an excellent library to aid you with this, [Commons Lang StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

```
StringUtils.join(C, ",");
```

where `C` can be either a Collection, Array, or Iterator.

Answer (score 3):

The lang library of Apache Commons has a nice method for this:

```
StringUtils.join(java.util.Collection,char)
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is groovy, why not just do:

```
String ourOutput = (0..9).join( ',' )
```

Answer (score 3):

As it's Groovy code, a concise solution is to store each item in a List then join the List to create a comma-separated string, e.g.

```
List ourOutput = []

for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++) {
  if (/*some condition goes here*/) {
    ourOutput << i
  }
}

String commaSeparated = ourOutput.join(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this task in two step:

- split `String` variable by one to one character (it means : `test` ==>> String{"t","e","s","t"})
- join array reult in above step by [Apache Commons Lang3](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331723164478&sqi=2&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://commons.apache.org/lang/&ei=nXtgT5eJA8jWtAb3yc27CQ&usg=AFQjCNGhJ4lqedPq0ei_GCZKVzq-CLw_iw&sig2=WhpXjtC_OX_iNwKuVtssHQ)

I write a utility method for this task:

```
public static String join(String src, String separator)
{
        String[] array = src.split("\\.?");

        String newString = StringUtils.join(array, separator);
        String finalResult = newString.substring(1, newString.length());

        System.out.println(finalResult);

        return finalResult;
}
```

if you execute this method with two argument as `TEST` and `,` you will see following output in console:

`T,E,S,T`

I hope my answer useful for you.

Comment: In Groovy, your entire function body can be replaced with: `src.toList().join( separator )`

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks for your comment. Do you means: " `src.toList()` statement in `Groovy` equals with `src.split("\\.?")` in `Java` "

Comment: not exactly, `src.toList()` calls [`toList` on a String](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#toList()), which _"Converts the given String into a List of strings of one character."_.  You don't get the initial empty char as you do with the `split`

Comment: Oh, That's right. I am looking in `java.lang.String` class and see it has a similar method with `toCharArray()` name.

Comment: Yeah, but then Groovy doesn't have a `join` method on `char[]`, so `toList` is a faster route ;-)

Comment: `Java` doesn't have a 'join' method in original `String` class also, I found it in `StringUtils` class in `Apache Commons Lang 3` ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just showing how it could be done in Groovy (as the question is tagged Groovy, and the original code is Groovy) ;)

Comment: I like those how have high accuracy and explain complete. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to add separator to any array.

**Defining joinSeparator()**

```
public static String joinSeparator(Object[] array, char separator) {
        if (array == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = array.length;

        int bufSize = (endIndex - startIndex);
        if (bufSize <= 0) {
            return null;
        }

        bufSize *= ((array[startIndex] == null ? 16 : array[startIndex]
                .toString().length()) + 1);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(bufSize);

        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
            if (i > startIndex) {
                buf.append(separator);
            }
            if (array[i] != null) {
                buf.append(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
```

**Call joinSeparator() method**

```
String[] array = {"sunil", "kumar", "sahoo"};
    joinSeparator(array, ',');
```

Comment: `java.util.Collection` is not of type `Object[]`

Comment: This is easily the most complicated solution to a simple problem I've seen for a while.

Comment: @Johan, The only difference is that you are doing the same thing by using library. I am not sure whether you have seen anything great in programming without using external library, and by writing any logic by yourself

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo, I've written a few of these myself manually. I'm quite sure they can be quite a bit shorter and easier to follow. No disrespect to your code though.