# Output Commas between Elements

Tags: c++, performance, coding-style

my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699460/what-is-the-better-way-to-add-commas-to-multiple-elements-string-output), but I don't want to use a library for this.

Imagine we have an array of names we want to output.

```
string names[] = { "Peter", "Max", "Jack", "Daniel", "Luke" };

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(names); i++)
{
    cout << names[i];
}
```

Output: `PeterMaxJackDanielLuke`

This isn't exactly what we call user friendly so let's output commas between the names.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(names); i++)
{
    cout << names[i] << ", ";
}
```

Output: `Peter, Max, Jack, Daniel, Luke,`

The problem is the ending comma. With `if` I could check every loop of `for` if it is the last element, but this doesn't seems to be a clean solution.

**What is the best way to insert commas between the elements without using a library?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there’s a bug in your code, `sizeof(names)` will yield the wrong value.

To get the comma in the right places, the conventional way is as follows:

```
string names[] = { "Peter", "Max", "Jack", "Daniel", "Luke" };
bool first = true;

for(auto const& name : names) {
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        cout << ", ";
    cout << name;
}
```

Or, if you are not using C++11:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]); ++i) {
    if (i > 0)
        cout << ", ";
    cout << names[i];
}
```

But this:

> What is the best way to insert commas between the elements without using a library?

Is the wrong attitude. C++ specifically works well only when you use libraries. Without libraries, C++ is a bad language. Or, in the words of Stroustrup:

> Without a good library, most interesting tasks are hard to do in C++; but given a good library, almost any task can be made easy.

Comment: @Luchian It will yield the size of the array *in bytes*, not the number of elements.

Comment: why adding a boolean and not just *if (i > 0) cout << ","* ?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: it should be `sizeof(names)/sizeof(string)`

Comment: @guido: that would omit the comma after the FIRST entry, not after the last entry.

Comment: @Rudy That entirely depends on where you put the statement. Look at my code with guido’s amendment, it works just fine.

Comment: Heck, i thought I had cancelled that comment. Sorry for that. I had already seen that my comment was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the bug, your answer and explanation about libraries. accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`boost::join`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.join_hpp):

```
std::cout << boost::join(names, ", ") << "\n";
```

because there is no point rewriting the function... although it certainly is simple enough.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how `join` works. Do you have an idea where we can see the implementation?

Comment: @sharethis: all the boost code is available (either you can download it or sometimes view it online), so enjoy: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp ; having already implemented it a couple times before I realized it was available in Boost, the principle is easy: check for emptiness (do nothing), output first element, loop on the rest putting first the separator and then an element. Using a boolean `first` you can avoid specializing the first element and hope the compiler optimizes it away.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, it is the way Konrad Rudolph wrote. upvote.

Comment: @sharethis: yep, `join` is simple enough that there are only two real implementations. Either you use a boolean or your specialize for emptiness and put the first element out of the loop (or last... but first is easier when dealing with iterators). Boost implementation is "better" because it's built on top of Boost.Range and so automatically deal with C arrays even though they don't have `begin` and `end` methods; sugar coating is good :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
string names[] = { "Peter", "Max", "Jack", "Daniel", "Luke" };
int i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]) - 1; i++)
{
    cout << names[i] << ", "; 
}   
cout << names[i];
```

That is what I usually do.

Comment: This has two disadvantages though: first, it creates a different loop condition – almost always a bad idea. Loops should be over ranges, this allows checking correctness by eyeballing the code (also makes static checking easier). Secondly, it requires you to type the logic twice. Granted, it’s a simple statement but it’s still code duplication and while it doesn’t make the code physically bigger, it still makes it *more complex*.

Comment: But it completely avoids the test (and branch). Sure, it requires you to type the logic twice, but as you said, no big problem in this case. IOW, I would not do this if the logic were more complex. Having different loop conditions is no big problem, IMO. After all, the range of items that should be followed by a comma is well defined.

Comment: I am looking for a way of doing this without code duplication and without an `if` statement every loop. Maybe `join` is a better solution.

Comment: FWIW, `join` does something similar internally.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a clean solution, but it is the only solution.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(names); i++)
{
    cout << names[i] << (i==sizeof(names)-1)?"",", ";
}
```